# how to check if a post exists by title AND post type

Tags: wordpress, posts

I am trying to add a new blog post when an event (custom post type) is created and edit the post when the event is updated. So far I have been able to add the new post when an event is created but it also creates a new post when the event is saved so I need to check if the post already exists in the blog before doing the insert. I tried the post_exists(title) function but then it stopped creating posts altogether so I think the issue is that I need a way to check if the post exists by a specific post type?

here is what I have so far:

```
 function create_event_post( $post_id ) {

    // If this is just a revision, don't create post.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $post_content = get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID);
    $featured_image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full');
    $author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);
    $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' , $author_id );  
    $slug = 'event';


// If the post is not "tribe_events", don't create a new post.  
    if ( "tribe_events" != $post_type ) 
        return;

    $post_id = post_exists( $my_title );
    if (!$post_id) {
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
            'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
            'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
            'post_title'        =>  $post_title,
            'post_content'      =>  $post_content,
            'post_status'       =>  'publish',
            'post_type'     =>  'post'
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'create_event_post' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working now. Ended up using the [`get_page_by_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) function and passed it 'post' as post type then checked if it was empty.

Here is the final solution I came up with:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'create_event_post' );

function create_event_post( $post_id ) {

    // Set the title, thumbnail id, author, and content variables
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $post_content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    $author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);

    // If the post is not "tribe_events", don't create a new post.  
    if ( "tribe_events" != $post_type ) 
        return;

    $new_post = array(
                'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
                'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
                'post_title'        =>  $post_title,
                'post_content'      =>  $post_content,
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'post_type'     =>  'post'
            );

    remove_action( 'save_post', 'create_event_post' );

    $post_exists = get_page_by_title( $post_title, $output, "post" );

    if ( !empty($post_exists) ) {
        // Update post
        $update_post = array(
            'ID'           =>   $post_exists->ID,
            'post_title'   =>   $post_title,
            'post_content' =>   $post_content,
        );

        // Update the post into the database
        wp_update_post( $update_post );
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_exists->ID, $thumbnail_id );
    }
    else {
        // Create the new post and retrieve the id of the new post
        $new_post_id = wp_insert_post ( $new_post );
        // Set the featured image for the new post to the same image as event post 
        set_post_thumbnail( $new_post_id, $thumbnail_id );
    }           

    // Now hook the action
    add_action( 'save_post', 'create_event_post' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had better use custom field to check i will change your code a bit

```
    $post_child_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'child-post', true);
     if (!$post_child_id) {
        $post_child_id = wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
            'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
            'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
            'post_title'        =>  $post_title,
            'post_content'      =>  $post_content,
            'post_status'       =>  'publish',
            'post_type'     =>  'post'
        )

    );
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'child-post', $post_child_id);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem of adding duplicate posts. Now I just need to know how to update the post content if the post already exists.

Comment: you need add else clause and update everything you want

Comment: i tried adding an else clause like you suggested but i get a 502 Bad Gateway when i try to save an event now. here's what i added:`else { $my_post = array( 'post_content' => $post_content ); wp_update_post( $my_post ); }`